# GCM not delivering Amazon SNS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I've set up a AWS server and an Android app with push notifications using GCM and SNS.

The app registers successfully, i.e. the `BroadcastReceiver` gets a notification with the registration ID. Problem is no SNS notifications go through.

Is there a way to check if the notification was received by the device, but not delivered to the `BroadcastReceiver` for some reason?

Also, maybe I've done something wrong (possibly with the package name)? Here is the manifest:

```
...
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.package.tester"
... >
<permission
    android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
...
<application
    ... >
    <service android:name="my.package.path.to.PushNotificationsService" >
    </service>
...
    <receiver android:name="my.package.path.to.PushNotificationsBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" />

            <category android:name="my.package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
...
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but finally I've found that the problem was not in the client side after all. The problem was I put `JSONObject.toString()` in the data value instead of just `JSONObject`.

Apparently GCM can't handle that, but doesn't throw out any error either...

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can check:

- The receiver requires `com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND` permission. Please add `android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"` in the receiver block
- The category of the intent filter should match your application name
- If your device connects to WIFI, make sure GCM port (5228, 5229, and 5230) are whitelisted.

Further reading:

- [Implementing GCM Client on Android](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)
- [GCM HTTP Connection Server](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html)
- [Amazon SNS: Getting Started with Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html)